# Unpacking vectors in dataframe gives error

Tags: r, dataframe, unnest

I'm trying to download some data and plot them. Some columns contain vectors containing multiple entries (e.g. fields.species). I would like to unpack these vectors so that I can plot these values later on using ggplot.

Currently I have:

```
library(jsonlite)
library(tidyverse)

query = "https://www.ebi.ac.uk/ebisearch/ws/rest/pride?query=submitter_country:Norway&size=1000&fields=species&format=json"

datasets.raw <- fromJSON(query, flatten = TRUE, simplifyDataFrame = TRUE)
datasets.raw
datasets.df <- do.call(rbind, datasets.raw) #convert to dataframe
unpack <- datasets.df %>% select(id, fields.species) %>% unnest(fields.species)
```

However, the last line returns me the error

> Error in `col_to_long()`: ! Can't combine `..1$fields.species`
> integer and `..3$fields.species` character. Run
> `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.
>
> unpack <- datasets.df %>% select(id, fields.species) %>% unnest(fields.species) Error in `list_unchop()`: ! Can't combine
> `x[[1]]` integer and `x[[2]]` character. Run `rlang::last_trace()`
> to see where the error occurred.

Both 'unnest()', 'unnest_longer()' and 'unnest_wider()' fails to give any usable result. What is wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were pretty close, had you opened the `dataset.raw` in `Viewer()` , I'm sure you would have found the `entries` data.frame and `fields.species` list-column that can be unnested with `unnest()` or `unnest_longer()`:
[image: viewer output]

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(jsonlite)

query = "https://www.ebi.ac.uk/ebisearch/ws/rest/pride?query=submitter_country:Norway&size=1000&fields=species&format=json"

datasets.raw <- fromJSON(query, flatten = TRUE, simplifyDataFrame = TRUE)
as_tibble(datasets.raw$entries) %>% 
  unnest(fields.species)
#> # A tibble: 239 × 3
#>    id        source fields.species                             
#>    <chr>     <chr>  <chr>                                      
#>  1 PXD018812 pride  Mus Musculus (mouse)                       
#>  2 PXD025087 pride  Andreprevotia Sp. Igb-42                   
#>  3 PXD032830 pride  Cyprinidae                                 
#>  4 PXD033425 pride  Danio Rerio (zebrafish) (brachydanio Rerio)
#>  5 PXD033425 pride  Mycobacterium Marinum                      
#>  6 PXD011399 pride  Rattus Norvegicus (rat)                    
#>  7 PXD002106 pride  Rattus Norvegicus (rat)                    
#>  8 PXD000656 pride  Homo Sapiens (human)                       
#>  9 PXD005931 pride  Homo Sapiens (human)                       
#> 10 PXD009302 pride  Homo Sapiens (human)                       
#> # ℹ 229 more rows
```

`jsonlite` simplifications usually works, though sometimes it may be better to check the JSON structure outside of R / RStudio first, for example in browser's dev tools:
[image: json sample]

, set `simplifyVector = FALSE` and just go through rectangling process yourself:

```r
fromJSON(query, simplifyVector = FALSE) %>% 
  getElement("entries") %>%
  bind_rows() %>% 
  unnest_longer(fields)
#> # A tibble: 239 × 3
#>    id        source fields                                     
#>    <chr>     <chr>  <chr>                                      
#>  1 PXD018812 pride  Mus Musculus (mouse)                       
#>  2 PXD025087 pride  Andreprevotia Sp. Igb-42                   
#>  3 PXD032830 pride  Cyprinidae                                 
#>  4 PXD033425 pride  Danio Rerio (zebrafish) (brachydanio Rerio)
#>  5 PXD033425 pride  Mycobacterium Marinum                      
#>  6 PXD011399 pride  Rattus Norvegicus (rat)                    
#>  7 PXD002106 pride  Rattus Norvegicus (rat)                    
#>  8 PXD000656 pride  Homo Sapiens (human)                       
#>  9 PXD005931 pride  Homo Sapiens (human)                       
#> 10 PXD009302 pride  Homo Sapiens (human)                       
#> # ℹ 229 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2023-07-04 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>